# JSX element type 'App' is not a constructor function for JSX elements. Property 'context' is missing in type 'App'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to implement unit tests for my typescript react application (existing application, i.e not from scratch)

I am using jest + enzyme frameworks with below versions, but unfortunately I am getting error.

> "JSX element type 'App' is not a constructor function for JSX
>   elements. Property 'context' is missing in type 'App'."

For basic tests also, I tried all possibilities , deleting `package-lock.json` and tried different versions of `@types/react` but I'm not able to resolve, please help.

I am executing simple tests like this:

```
import * as React from "react";

import * as ReactShallowRenderer from "react-test-renderer/shallow";
import { App } from './../src/App';

describe("<App />", () => {

  it("renders", () => {

    const renderer = new ReactShallowRenderer();

    expect(renderer.render(<App />)).toMatchSnapshot();});
});

test('render a label', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<App/>);
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Here's the error:
[image]

And here's my package.json:

```
"react": "16.7.0",
"react-dom": "16.7.0",
"@types/enzyme": "3.1.15",
"@types/jest": "23.3.11",
"@types/react": "16.7.18",
"ts-jest": "23.10.5",
"jest": "23.6.0",
"jest-cli": "23.6.0",
"enzyme": "3.3.0"
```

Please help me how to fix this issue.

Comment: I haven't been working with enzyme myself but the error indicates that `renderer.render` expects a HoC with a `context` injected to it and that you should use a different API. In fact googling for some articles yields the following snippet: `const component = shallow(<App />); expect(component).toMatchSnapshot();` Which is pretty much what you have the bottom of your code.